# jQuery next() for class attr

Tags: jquery

Html Code

```
<span class="Play" href ="media/Tagged - 357.mp3">
<span class="Play" href ="media/Tagged - 358.mp3">
<span class="Play" href ="media/Tagged - 359.mp3">
<span class="Play" href ="media/Tagged - 360.mp3">
```

I am try to set up a song player next/previous song buttons. Is it possible to get the next class attr href?

```
$("#fwd_btn").on('tap touch click',function () {        
    if(theMP3 !=undefined){
        theMP3.stop();
        currentSong++;
    }

    url_new = $(".Play").next().attr('href');
    playSound(url_new);

});
```

---

Okay looking at your actual code, the spans do not look like what you have above. They are NOT siblings, they are inside of elements so the next() will fail. Plus not sure why a span has an href, would be better to use a data attribute.

Second I ran a test

[image]

and it shows that it finds an element. So unless currentSong does not have the correct value, I not sure why that would not work.

What you have in the code is  `$(this).find(".Play")` which means you are looking for `<button><span class="Play" /></button>` which I know is not what you have.

Comment: @epascarelio Since when editing question is same as answering it?

Answer (score 0):

So how do you know what is active?

If there is a class

```
url_new = $(".Play.active").next(".Play").attr('href');
```

If there is no class, than use the index

```
url_new = $(".Play").eq(currentSong).attr('href');
// might need to subtract 1 from currentSong...
```

Comment: Still can't get it. Here is the site if any suggestions. [link](http://hiphopbeatz.com)

Comment: Well it is because url_new = `$(this).find('.Play').attr('href');` What is `this`? It is the button!!!! That is one reason why it does not work.

Comment: Sorry I was trying different things.. I changed it back to what you suggested but still no luck.

Comment: Is there anything else I should look at? Do I need to add something to the Play class to make it active?

Comment: Okay thanks! The Index code above works great only it always starts from the first song on the page. Any way to have it go from the current playing song?

Comment: Um, is currentSong not updated with the song that is playing?